# Free Pascal multiple interfaces problem

Tags: interface, casting, corba, freepascal

This may prove difficult -- I'm using multiple CORBA interfaces on an object, so it looks somehow like this:

```
TBaseObject = class(TSuperBaseObject, IInterfaceA)
  function Afunction; // implemented from IInterfaceA
end;

TOtherObject = class(TBaseObject, IInterfaceB);  
  function Bfunction; // implemented from IInterfaceB
end;
```

Now I have a function that takes a variant, and in case that variant is an object, it assumes that object to be a IInterfaceA object:

```
case var.vtype of
  ...
  vtObject     : begin
    Something := (var.vObject as IInterfaceA).AFunction; (1)
  end;
end;
```

Now once I run that code, and pass a TOtherObject to the function, in line (1) BFunction gets called with forced parameters!

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in the compiler? Also, any sane way to circumvent that without changing the class structure?

Full code for a EAccessViolation if anyone wants to try - http://pastebin.com/D7sDpDHx

Answer (score 2):

Reported this as a bug to the FPC bugtracker - http://bugs.freepascal.org/view.php?id=20076

It turned out that FPC doesn't identify CORBA interfaces internally. To solve the problem one needs to identify them by himself:

```
type IInterfaceA = interface['interface_a']
   function AFunction;
end;
```

Then the `as` keyword will work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about FreePascal, but in Delphi you would use the supports function to query the interface.

```
var
    IntfA : IInterfaceA;
    IntfB : IInterfaceB;
 begin 
 case var.vtype of
  ...
  vtObject : begin
             if supports(var.vObject,IInterfaceA,IntfA) then
               Something := IntfA.AFunction
             else if supports(var.vObject,IInterfaceB,IntfB) then
               Something := IntfB.BFunction;
             end;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: +1: FPC doesn't seem to have the supports keyword, it also uses CORBA style interfaces, not COM, but the answer put me on the right track of searching.